# Converting std::string ** to char *** and it happens to work. How?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
std::vector<std::string> foo{{"blee"}, {"bleck"}, {"blah0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}};
std::string *temp = foo.data();
char*** bar = reinterpret_cast<char***>(&temp);

for (size_t i = 0; i < foo.size(); ++i){
    std::cout << (*bar)[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Clearly this is sketchy code, but it happens to work.

http://ideone.com/2XAJYR

I would like to know why it works? Are there some strange rules of C++ I don't know about? Or is it just bad code and undefined behaviour?

I made one of the strings huge in case there was some small-string optimization going on.

Adapted from: [Cast a vector of std::string to char***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687751/cast-a-vector-of-stdstring-to-char/29031944#29031944)

Comment: it's possible that the string stores the pointer to its buffer as the first structure member, hence its address is the same as that of the string object itself. I wouldn't say "it works"; it's rather *pretending* to work.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant yes I bet on it too, but I don't think it's a good idea to rely on that creating code that should always work...

Comment: I think it has to do with std::vector behaviour. It **guarantees** to have continous memory and even copies and moves its data around to do fulfill this guarantee. If put in there static std::strings of fixed memory size, they are beeing placed in continous block of memory and you can do tricks like that :). To check it you can push_back another string in your vector and see if your prevoius data pointers are still valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very much undefined behaviour.

It will appear to "work" if the string implementation happens to contain a pointer to the string data as its only data member, so that an array of `string` has the same memory layout as an array of `char*`. That is the case for at least one popular implementation (GNU), but is certainly not something you can rely on.

Comment: this is a particularly nasty one when you're dealing with C libraries. I've seen some cases where a `std::string` is passed as `void *`, which works great until someone decides to recompile with `clang`.

Comment: @Shep: If you're dealing with C libraries, then use `c_str()` to get a C-compatible pointer in a well-defined manner. Dodgy type-punning is nasty in any situation.

Comment: @Shep except, that might be ok! There's a paradigm known as "opaque pointers" or "opaque handles" that let's you specify e.g. user-data to be passed to callback functions. The library will not interpret the `void*` in any way in these situations. The user-callback _knows_ what the type actually is and can cast it back. (PS. Of course that's passing `&string` instead of the string itself as `void*`)

Comment: What I don't understand is why `(*bar)[i]` knows to increment the size of the string object to the next, and doesn't just go by one pointer.

Comment: @NeilKirk: As I said, it "works" if a `char*` pointer is the **only** data member, so that an array of `string` has the same layout as an array of `char*`. It will explode if it contains other data members.

Comment: I thought string had to contain size and capacity info also. Maybe it got optimized out.

Comment: @NeilKirk: In the case of the GNU implementation, that's stored just before the string data in memory, accessible via the pointer in the string object.

Comment: Ooooooooo now it makes sense. I assumed that size and capacity would be member variables of the string object itself.

Comment: @MikeSeymour When you say GNU implementation are you talking gcc? Cause on gcc 4.9.2 I'm seeing just the strings, not any gibberish before them: http://ideone.com/w6B55W

Comment: @JonathanMee: The pointer points to the string data, so printing that just prints the string. There's some more information stored in the memory before the string, which the implementation can access by subtracting some offset from the pointer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour So that's what you were talking about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687751/cast-a-vector-of-stdstring-to-char/29031944?noredirect=1#comment46307814_29031944

Comment: @JonathanMee: Yes, I gave a sketch answer to the same question there.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Welp, I learned a lot today. I love this site for that, but man if the down voting doesn't get pretty brutal.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour depends on your STL implementation (just revise std::vector and std::string source code). Occasionaly, you have the string impl that stores (as other participants mentioned) pointer to chars buffer as a member.

It's not a secret that one shoudn't rely on incapsulated details of implementation due to undefined behaviour it causes.

Answer (score 2):

After [Neil Kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2068573/neil-kirk) mentioned this in a comment on the answer that originally sparked all this, I looked it up.

`string` is a specialization of `basic_string` on all implementations.

Now I only have access to Visual Studio's 2013 version of xstring.h (here Microsoft implements `basic_string`) so this may be different for other versions or compilers. But in xstring.h `basic_string` inherits from `_String_alloc` which inherits from `_String_val`.

`_String_val` is actually the first in the inheritance chain which has any member variables. It's first member variable, `_Bx`, is a `union` which will translate to a `char*` for `string` (not for `wstring`).

So when a `string` is cast to a `char*` on Visual Studio 2013 it is a `char*` which begins pointing to the member variable: `_Bx` Since `_Bx` *is* actually a `'\0'`-terminated `char*` you can `cout` it and it behave's properly.

Now what I didn't know, and what all this research taught me, is that `_String_val` also contains a size variable, `_Mysize`, and a reserved size, `_Myres`. If either of those had been declared in `_String_val` before `_Bx` this would have outputted gibberish at the start of `cout`'s output each line.

I'd conclude by conceding that as is mentioned by the other answers this behavior is implementation dependent, and may not work across diferent versions or platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As The Parametric Croissant's comment suggest, it is necessary for this to work that the `char[]` member of the string class is the first member so that the string address == the char[] beginning.

I couldn't find any explicit mention of this in the standard.
It is possible that some other rule in the standard implicitly imposes this one, but I didn't find one.

Therefore you shouldn't rely on it.

Nota :
Another more obvious necessity is that std::vector provides contiguous memory space, but this is specififed.